# How create combined variable in Ansible from multiple hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Scenario example:

*inventory.ini file:*

```
[web-servers]
web1.local ansible_host=10.10.10.11
web2.local ansible_host=10.10.10.12
web3.local ansible_host=10.10.10.13

...
```

also, let's say I have a *playbook.yml* ready to be executed

```
- hosts: web-servers
  become: true
  role: 
    - xxx
    - yyy
```

Wanted result is JSON VARIABLE  `var_a = [{'hostname':'web1.local', 'ip_address':'10.10.10.11' }, {'hostname':'web2.local', 'ip_address':'10.10.10.12' },{'hostname':'web3.local', 'ip_address':'10.10.10.13'}]`
This variable should be visible in roles

**Question: Is this even possible and if yes how to achieve it?**

The purpose of this is to append `/etc/hosts` in all web-servers (information about all web servers in a group). When the playbook is executed Variable will be used to fill host entries and for other purposes.

Maybe ansible has other methods to achieve this

Comment: I have answered the question as I think you might be new to ansible and stackoverflow. But in the future, please ask for your queries and not direct answers by sharing your approach and specific error traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the below host file

```
[default]
localhost

[web-server]
w1 ansible_host=192.168.5.100
w2 ansible_host=192.168.5.101
w3 ansible_host=192.168.5.102
```

And the task to achieve the JSON is shown below,

```
- name: asdasd
  set_fact:
    hosts_dict : "{{ hosts_dict|default([]) + [ {'hostname': item, 'ip_address': hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] } ] }}"
  with_items: " {{ groups['web-server'] }}"
```

The output is shown below [ displayed the value of hosts_dict using debug module ],

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "hostname": "w1",
            "ip_address": "192.168.5.100"
        },
        {
            "hostname": "w2",
            "ip_address": "192.168.5.101"
        },
        {
            "hostname": "w3",
            "ip_address": "192.168.5.102"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary might be more useful. For example

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        hosts_dict: "{{ dict(names|zip(ips)) }}"
      vars:
        names: "{{ groups.web_servers }}"
        ips: "{{ groups.web_servers|map('extract',hostvars,'ansible_host')|list }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: hosts_dict
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  hosts_dict:
    web1.local: 10.10.10.11
    web2.local: 10.10.10.12
    web3.local: 10.10.10.13
```